# MySQL update content if exists

Tags: mysql, database

Ok, so I know there are some questions similar, but how would I update a table like this in MySQL:

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------+
| id | username | subject | content                 |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------+
| 1  | Fred     | English | Lorem Ipsum             |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------+
```

So lets say, i want to update the content in the users English book, however, I want to insert it if it is not already in there, and then in te future update it.

Comment: Can one user have more than one English book? If yes, which one do you want to update on insert?

Comment: @Quassnoi One user can have one English book only

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Answer (score 0):

If one user can only have one book on a subject, you should create a unique index on `(username, subject)` and use this query:

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (username, subject, content)
VALUES  (:username, :subject, :content)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  content = VALUES(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create an unique index on the columns you want to be unique. Then the query is like that:

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`username`, `subject`, `content`)
VALUES ('[value 1]', '[value 2]', '[value 3]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `username` = '[value 1]', `subject` = '[value 2]', `content` = '[value 3]';
```